# System.setProperty or public static variable?

Tags: java, static

I understand that `System.setProperty(“key”,”value”)` and `System.getProperty(“key”)` are used to hold and retrieve system properties and user-defined properties. The values set can be accessed everywhere within the application.

Also, I am aware that when a variable is declared `public` and `static`, it becomes a constant and is available everywhere within the application.

I would like to know of the 2 which is advantageous and a better option. One aspect I could think of is System.setProperty is useful when we want to retrieve a value in an xml file[using ${key}]. The same can not be achieved using public static variable.

**My questions are**

1. Are there any other benefits?
2. Which one is a better option?
3. On what scenarios should one go with System.setProperty/getProperty and public static variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems broad, but IMHO **don't** use `System.getProperty` in this way:
As you told, you can create a Constants class with `public static final` variables. You can also define a properties file and `Map` into an object with key value....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I totally agree that we can use a **properties** file or **Map** [ _In fact, that is how I have  been doing all these years_ ]. But, I don't see a concrete reason why one should not use **System.getProperty** instead.  Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: you can, but this is a misunderstanding of System.getProperty. It **should** be used to store the properties of the system.

Answer (score 0):

A Setter can have further tests. Like testing against null, test against bad values etc...

A Setter is usually a better option, yet, a class without Setters could be even better, don't give the user ways of destroying your program

```
public static Variable variable;

//In other file
variable = null;
```

And public static variables are not thread-safe at all!!!(Maybe if it's atomic)

Unless dealing with something I really want to be changed a lot, like a Vector2D/3D I never use public static (and in this cases it's not public static anyway because it isn't static). To add to this, I only make it because the user can't null out x,y,z because it's a float/int. Usually I go with methods that do what I want and not simple Setters.

(Ex: Not a good example but I think it shows what I meant. Instead of Person.setState(State.EATING) using Person.eat())

Answer (score 0):

When you run a java program, you are actually starting a JVM instance. That instance will have it's own System properties. That is where you can put your properties. When you run another program, it will have it's own System properties.

A Properties object is a sub-type of Hash-table and it is also thread-safe. But if you want to use a public static variable you also have to handle synchronous access in multi-threaded programs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get your point, but my question is, is it a **good practice** to use System.setProperty/getProperty to **store** and **retrieve key-value pairs** **_instead_** of going for Map or Properties which is declared as _public_ and _static_.